# using __setitem__ requires to also implement __len__ in python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

This very simple snippet fails on python 2 but passes with python 3:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        pass

r = A(1)
r[80:-10] = list(range(10))
```

On python2, the interpreter make a call to `__len__` which does not exist and therefore fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 9, in <module>
AttributeError: A instance has no attribute '__len__'
```

Where is this behaviour documented? It doesn't make sense to force a container to have a size.

Comment: It doesn't. Using a negative integer in a slice does though because `r[80:-10]` is automatically translated into `r[80:len(r)-10]`. This makes sense in a way, How do you calculate a negative index without a length? This is why negative indices aren't valid in `itertools.islice`.

Comment: Shouldn't the `__setitem__` method receive a slice as an argument and deal with the negative indexing itself?

Comment: Yes, and that's what happens in python3

Comment: That's what happens in Python 2, as well, assuming `A` is a new-style class.

Comment: @chepner ahhh that's the issue

Comment: Yeah, I just realized I had tested a new-style class out of habit.

Comment: @chpner thanks! Can you please write an answer (with a link to https://bugs.python.org/issue21785 maybe) so I can mark this as resolved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an old-style class quirk. Old-style classes have a lot of poorly-documented quirks, mostly old behavior that hasn't kept up with changes to Python.

Here, `types.InstanceType` [has a `__setslice__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.15/Objects/classobject.c#L1263), which is responsible for looking up the old-style class `__setitem__` and `__setslice__`. Since this `__setslice__` exists, Python tries to go through `__setslice__`, which requires a `len` call first for negative slice indexes. Your (old-style) class doesn't have `__len__`, so the call fails.

Use a new-style class:

```
class A(object):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you're using an old-style class. In python 2 the syntax for a new-style class (which are the only kind of classes in python 3) is

```
class T(object):
    ...
```